# ignore_dup_key vs SSIS Lookup in a SQL Server Batch import

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have to do a Import of my live table (25M rows) to a new table with Identity column before I cutover.
I implemented two set of process. Batch import SP which will import records whose creation timestamp is less than or equal to my batch import initialization time and triggers capture all insert/update/delete that happens after I initialize the batch import.

This live table does not have an Identity column and even though batch import works based on a unique key column(nvarchar(255)), new incoming records are not ordered similar to identity column, so I am ending up with the situation where a same key column is called more than once by my batch process that results in

```
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.newtable' with unique index 'IX_key'. The duplicate key value is
```

This is a problem which we cannot address now, I wanted to ignore/bypass this duplicate error and proceed with my batch process, since the record is already present in target table.

I am currently testing two options.

1. Created SSIS package with Lookup between by source and target and inserting only Lookup no match output into the target. This is extremely slow for the reason(Im guessing) source table has a nvarchar(max) column. Loading of ~19M rows took 7.30 hours. Not sure if I can do that in my PROD.
2. I also stumbled upon some articles about setting IGNORE_DUP_KEY to ON for the unique which will quietly ignore the duplicate instead of erroring.

Option 2 seems more suitable in my case, but I dont know what are the pros and cons of these methods and choose which one to implement.

In both approaches, basically the target table is checked if the record is already present and only inserted after right? Which approach is a more optimal thing to do in terms of performance and my implementation should not disturb the current production workload because it is a critical service.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your second paragraph.  Can you explain more, perhaps with sample table ddl and data?